# Pre_get_post on CPT archive page

Tags: wp-query, query, pre-get-posts

i would change the main query on a CPT archive page

the CPT is declare as "events", the name of the archive page I use is called 'archive-events.php" and this simple code won't work.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_post_fct' );

function pre_get_post_fct( $wp_query ) {

    if( $wp_query->is_main_query() ) :

        echo "A";

    endif;

}
```

The thing is, I don't understand why it doesn't echo "A".
I probably miss something....

Could you help me please ? Thanks !

Comment: where is this code located? It's unlikely that an `A` will be output in a place that's visible on the frontend without viewing source, and the filter your shared runs on _all_ queries that are the main query. I suspect though that you've placed that filter inside `archive-events.php` which is far too late. Adding filters inside a theme template is a general anti-pattern and rarely works

Comment: Thanks to reply, the code is located in "archive-events.php" just before 
<?php get_header(); ?>

Comment: Writing it in function.php make it works. Of course. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`pre_get_posts` filters run before WordPress has figured out the main query, which is used to pick the template. For this reason you can't put it inside the template, it has to run *before* the template is picked, not afterwards.

For this reason, it has to go inside your themes `function.php` or in a plugin